# Writing stored procedure which flags duplicate values in a comma separated field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table like this sample:

```
ID   THINGS            HAS_DUPLICATES
1    AAA, BBB, AAA     NULL
2    CCC, DDD          NULL
```

I am trying to write a stored procedure to flag duplicate values in THINGS field.
After calling the procedure the table will become like this:

```
ID   THINGS            HAS_DUPLICATES
1    AAA, BBB, AAA     YES
2    CCC, DDD          NO
```

**Please be informed that I am trying to resolve it using only SQL and without normalizing my database. I am also aware of other approaches like writing PHP code.**

Comment: `"without normalizing my database"` - Why?  Using the right tool for the job is generally the preferred approach.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of values that could be stored in `things`?  If you do, you could use `substring_index` to create multiple columns and then compare accordingly without needing `dynamic sql` or a `stored procedure`.

Comment: I am sure there is a silver lining there user148, in the near future

Comment: split the string to rows and count them.  there are a few questions about how to do the split do an internet serach

Comment: We can't help you fix your procedure if you don't post it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question, assuming the data in THINGS field are separated by a bar '|'. Our original table will be myTABLE:

```
ID   THINGS            THINGSCount  THINGSCountUnique   HAS_DUPLICATES
1    AAA|BBB|AAA       NULL         NULL                NULL
2    CCC|DDD           NULL         NULL                NULL
```

**Step 1. Check the maximum number of values separated by a bar '|' in THINGS field:**

```
SELECT ROUND((CHAR_LENGTH(THINGS) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(THINGS,'|',''))) / CHAR_LENGTH('|')) + 1 FROM myTABLE;
```

**Step 2. Assuming the answer from step 1 was 7, now use the following SQL to split the data in THINGS field into rows, there are many other approaches which you can Google to do the split:**

```
CREATE TABLE myTABLE_temp 
SELECT ID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(myTABLE.THINGS, '|', n.n), '|', -1) THINGS 
FROM myTABLE JOIN 
( SELECT n FROM 
( SELECT 1 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 ) a ) n 
ON CHAR_LENGTH(THINGS) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(THINGS, '|', '')) >= n - 1 
ORDER BY ID;
```

Our myTABLE_temp table will be something like:

```
ID   THINGS
1    AAA
1    BBB
1    AAA
2    CCC
2    DDD
```

**Step 3. Here we create two new tables to hold COUNT(THINGS) and COUNT(DISTINCT THINGS) as following:**

```
# THINGSCount
CREATE TABLE myTABLE_temp_2 
SELECT ID, COUNT(THINGS) AS THINGSCount FROM myTABLE_temp GROUP BY ID;
# Remember to ADD INDEX to ID field
UPDATE myTABLE A INNER JOIN myTABLE_temp_2 B ON(A.ID = B.ID) SET A.THINGSCount = B.THINGSCount;

# THINGSCountUnique
CREATE TABLE myTABLE_temp_3 
SELECT ID, COUNT(THINGS) AS THINGSCountUnique FROM myTABLE_temp GROUP BY ID;
# Remember to ADD INDEX to ID field
UPDATE myTABLE A INNER JOIN myTABLE_temp_3 B ON(A.ID = B.ID) SET A.THINGSCountUnique = B.THINGSCountUnique;
```

**Final Step: Flag duplicate values:**

```
UPDATE myTABLE SET HAS_DUPLICATES = IF(THINGSCount>THINGSCountUnique, 'DUPLICATES', 'NO');
```

Answer (score 1):

Schema:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS evilThings; -- orig table with dupes
CREATE TABLE evilThings
(   ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    THINGS TEXT NOT NULL,
    HAS_DUPLICATES INT NULL
);
INSERT evilThings(ID,THINGS) VALUES 
(1,"'AAA, BBB, AAA'"),
(2,"'CCC, DDD'");


CREATE TABLE notEvilAssocTable
(   ai INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, --  no shuffle on inserts
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    THING VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `unqK_id_thing` (ID,THING) -- no dupes, this is honorable
);
```

Stored Proc:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS splitEm;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE splitEm()
BEGIN
    DECLARE lv_ID,pos1,pos2,comma_pos INT;
    DECLARE lv_THINGS TEXT;
    DECLARE particle VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE strs_done INT DEFAULT FALSE; -- string search done
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE; -- cursor done
    DECLARE cur111 CURSOR FOR SELECT ID,THINGS FROM evilThings ORDER BY ID;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    -- Please note in the above, CURSOR stuff MUST come LAST else "Error 1337: Variable or condition decl aft curs" 
    -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TRUNCATE TABLE notEvilAssocTable;

    OPEN cur111;

    read_loop: LOOP
        SET strs_done=FALSE;
        FETCH cur111 INTO lv_ID,lv_THINGS;

        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        SET pos1=1,comma_pos=0;
        WHILE !strs_done DO
            SET pos2=LOCATE(',', lv_THINGS, comma_pos+1);
            IF pos2=0 THEN
                SET pos2=LOCATE("'", lv_THINGS, comma_pos+1);
                IF pos2!=0 THEN
                    SET particle=SUBSTRING(lv_THINGS,comma_pos+1,pos2-comma_pos-1);
                    SET particle=REPLACE(particle,"'","");
                    SET particle=TRIM(particle);
                    INSERT IGNORE notEvilAssocTable (ID,THING) VALUES (lv_ID,particle);
                END IF;
                SET strs_done=1;
            ELSE
                SET particle=SUBSTRING(lv_THINGS,comma_pos+1,pos2-comma_pos-1);
                SET particle=REPLACE(particle,"'","");
                SET particle=TRIM(particle);
                INSERT IGNORE notEvilAssocTable (ID,THING) VALUES (lv_ID,particle);
                SET comma_pos=pos2;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cur111; -- close the cursor
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Test:

```
call splitEm();
```

See results of split:

```
select * from notEvilAssocTable;
```

[image]

Note that position 3, the InnoDB gap (from INSERT IGNORE). It is simply the innodb gap anomaly, an expected side effect like so many of InnoDB. In this case driven by the `IGNORE` part that creates a gap. No problem though. It forbids duplicates in our new table for split outs. It is common. It is there to protect you.

If you did not mean to have the single quote at the beginning and end of the string in the db, then change the routine accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @Drew for this nice answer. I tried it and it is working, but I can't mark it as the answer to my question since I want to FLAG duplicates not removing them. Please check my answer to the question.